# Convergence of solutions in initial value problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on the following problem:

Suppose $u_{n} : [-M, M] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable and are such that $u_{n}'(x) = F(u_{n}(x), x)$ for $F$ continuous and bounded. Furthermore, suppose $u'(x) = F(u(x), x)$, $u(x_{0}) = y_{0}$ has a unique solution $u$ on $[-M, M]$ and $u_{n}(x_{0}) \rightarrow y_{0}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Show that $u_{n}$ converges uniformly to $u$.

By Arzela-Ascoli, I can show that the $\{u_{n}\}$ are a compact subset of $\mathcal{C}([-M, M])$. Then $\{u_{n}\}$ has a (uniformly) convergent subsequence $u_{n_{k}} \rightarrow \widetilde{u}$. Then $\widetilde{u}'(x) = F(\widetilde{u}(x), x)$, but by the uniqueness of $u$, $\widetilde{u} = u$. If we remove the subsequence $\{u_{n_{k}}\}$ from the $\{u_{n}\}$, then we get another compact subset of $\mathcal{C}([-M, M])$. This has another convergent subsequence $\{u_{m_{k}}\}$ which by the same argument as before converges uniformly to $u$. However, how do I show that $u_{n}$ converges uniformly to $u$?

Comment: How do you know $\tilde u$ satisfies the differential equation?

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?